# Cache в приложении Android

Tags: android

Объясните мне на пальцах, как делать кэш в приложении. У меня приложение со статьями/новостями. Много списков, можно открывать элемент списка и читать новость.

Объясните прям на примере одного списка. Где что вызывать? как обращаться к кэшу? как всё хранить?

какой-нибудь самый простой способ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делается это так:

1. В отдельном потоке/сервисе читаем новости из сети
2. Прочитанные новости складываем в базу SQLite (обычно в виде JSon объектов)
3. Далее отображаем новости уже из базы SQLite

Если более подробно раскрыть п.3 то над БД SQLite разворачиваем `ContentProvider`, а список делаем через `CursorAdapter` над этим `ContentProvider`

Это рекомендованный Google'ом паттерн (не помню как называется)

**Update**
Чтобы это работал именно как кэш надо еще в фоне запускать сервис/поток, который раз в энное время будет просматривать БД и удалять устаревшие новости и/или удалять по [LRU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms) меткам. А собсно LRU метки можно проставлять при чтении новостей.

Answer (score 0):

Хорошая статья на эту тему:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

И я бы еще посмотрел в сторону *BufferedWriter*
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedWriter.html

Comment: Здесь не принято давать ссылки - хотите ответить, пишите законченный полный ответ. Ссылку можно указать, как дополнительный источник

Answer (score 0):

Сам когда то парился с кэшем. У меня создается файлик, никакой бд я не использую. Вот есть класс, который записывает и читает кэш:

```
public final class InternalStorage {
private InternalStorage() {}

        public static void writeObject(Context context, String key, Object object) throws IOException {
            Log.d("Cache", "WRITE: context");
            String path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + key;
            Log.e("path writeObject", path);
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(object);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
       }

       public static Object readObject(Context context, String key) throws IOException,
             ClassNotFoundException {
           String path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + key;
            Log.e("path readObject", path);
          FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(key);
          ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
          Object object = ois.readObject();
          return object;
       }
}
```

К примеру я получаю строку json и сохраняю ее в кэш:

```
    //создаю список обьектов
    private ArrayList<NewsObject> newLists;
    //вот так будет называться кэш
    private String nameCache = "News";
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //стандартный код
    //инициализация
    newLists = new ArrayList<NewsObject>();

    //пробуем читать кэш:
    try {
                newLists = (ArrayList<NewsObject>) InternalStorage.readObject(context, nameCache);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d("Cache", "Classnotfound");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Cache", "Exception " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    //если пустой, тогда грузим 
if(newLists.isEmpty()) {
            new NewsAsynkTask().execute();

        }
        else {
            //иначе просто врубаем адаптер с кэшем
            NewsAdapter adapter = new NewsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.n_news_object, newLists);
//тут ListView listNews
            listNews.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

     public class NewsAsynkTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void, String> {
    @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
     JSONObject jsonGETnews = null;

                 try {
//получаем json
                     jsonGETnews = new JSONObject(CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet(getNewsURL + link.getNews()).toString());
                     JSONArray newsTable = jsonGETnews.getJSONArray(TAG_TABLE);
    //в цикле добавляем в список newLists
      for(int i = 0; i < newsTable.length(); i++) {
//создаем обьект newsObject (ниже описан)
                        NewsObject newsObject = new NewsObject();
                        JSONObject c = newsTable.getJSONObject(i);

                         JSONObject news = c.getJSONObject(TAG_NEWS);
                         //получаем название
                         newsObject.setName(news.getString(TAG_TITLE));
    //добавляем в список
    newLists.add(newsObject);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
         return null;
            }

protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            //записываем в кэш
            try {
                InternalStorage.writeObject(context, nameCache, newLists);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Cache", e.getMessage());
            } 

//используем адаптер
            NewsAdapter adapter = new NewsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.n_news_object, newLists, mImageLoader);
            listNews.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Класс NewsObject, важно что б было `implements Serializable`

```
public class NewsObject implements Serializable{
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```